# Automatically dismiss/prevent notifications for reminders that were already completed on another device?

Tags: icloud, notifications, reminders

I have a reminder that is repeated daily.

I use three different Apple devices (work mac, home mac, phone) with the same iCloud account.

When I complete the reminder on device 1, Apple still shows me a notification for the same reminder on device device 2 and 3, sometimes hours after I completed the reminder on another device.

I still want to receive the reminder on all devices as I don't know on which device I will complete the reminder, but I don't want to see it on a device when I already completed it on another.

Is that possible?